# WPF DataGrid: Make cells readonly

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I use the following DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="OldValue" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=OldValue}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="NewValue" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding Path=NewValue}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I make the cells readonly?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Set DataGrid's [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly%28VS.95%29.aspx) property to true.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make the cells of a **certain column** readonly, you can set IsReadOnly for that column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: +1 The accepted answer is what I needed in my case, but I'm sure that this answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgUsers" 
    ...
    $dgUsers = $Form.FindName("dgUsers")
    ....
    # Make all columns cells readonly
    $dgUsers.Columns | ForEach-Object { $_.IsReadOnly = $True }
```